# py2exe change application name output

Tags: python, py2exe

I am working on my first Python project and I need compile with py2exe. I wrote this setup.py code :

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys
import os 

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    sys.argv.append("py2exe")

setup( options = {"py2exe": {"compressed": 1, "optimize": 2,"dll_excludes": "w9xpopen.exe",'dist_dir': "myproject", "ascii": 0, "bundle_files": 1}},
       zipfile = None,

       console = [
        {
            "script": "myapplication.py",                    ### Main Python script    
            "icon_resources": [(0, "favicon.ico")]     ### Icon to embed into the PE file.
        }
    ],)

os.system('upx -9 dist/*.exe')
os.system("rmdir /s /q build")
os.system("del /q *.pyc")
```

The setup code is working, but I need to change the name of the compiled application from myapplication to project.exe. What options for py2exe change the name of output application?

Comment: Set the ```name```-parameter as an argument to the setup-function ```setup(name="project", ...```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add `"dest_base" : "app_name"` to your console dict as such:

> ```
>    console = [
>     {
>         "script": "myapplication.py",                    ### Main Python script    
>         "icon_resources": [(0, "favicon.ico")], ### Icon to embed into the PE file.
>         "dest_base" : "app_name"
>     }]
> ```

Comment: I've had trouble finding that in the docs. Do you know where it is detailed?